# unsetting php reference

Tags: php, reference, unset

So I have this function, and it returns me a reference to a particular point to the array passed in. I want to make a call to unset that will then remove the result from the array/reference, but calling unset only removes the reference, not the data from the original array. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Setting the reference to `null` will destroy the data that the reference (and any other reference) is linked to.

See [Unsetting References](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php) in the manual for more on this.  Basically you want to do the following (taken from the comments):

```
$a = 1;
$b =& $a;
$c =& $b;  //$a, $b, $c reference the same content '1'

$b = null; //All variables $a, $b or $c are unset
```

In your case, it'll look something like this:

```
$a =& getArrayReference($whatever);
$a = null;
```

**EDIT**

To clear up any misconceptions, here's what you get when you unset array references:

```
$arr = array('x','y','z');

$x =& $arr[1];
unset($x);
print_r($arr);
//gives Array ( [0] => x [1] => y [2] => z )

$x =& $arr[1];
$x = null;
print_r($arr);
//gives Array ( [0] => x [1] => [2] => z )
```

Notice how the second array index does not have it's content deleted in the first example with `unset()`, but the second example of setting the reference to `null` accomplishes this.

Note:  If you need to unset the array index as well, which I'm a bit unclear on as to whether you do or not, then you'll need to find a way to reference the key of the array instead of the value, likely by altering the return value of your function.

Comment: That is not true. This will just set $a, $b and $c to "null". Consider this:
    
    <?php
    $a = array('foo', 'bar');
    $b = &$a[0];  
    $b = null;
    var_dump($a);

There would still be two values in the array $a;

Comment: @runish: That's what the original poster is trying to accomplish - the destruction of the referenced content.  Your example is wrong however.  There would still be two array indexes, but the data will be gone.

Comment: Only that the content is not destroyed, it is just nullified.

Comment: Nullification is the same as destruction in terms of getting it out of memory.  I clarified my answer a bit, as I'm unclear as to whether the poster requires that the array index itself be removed, or just the array value.

Comment: thanks for the thoughts guys. (1) i don't want it JUST nullified. i want it removed entirely from the array. is that the only solution?

Answer (score 1):

It is expected behavior that unsetting a reference does not unset the variable being referenced. One solution is to return the key instead of the value, and using that to unset the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the behavior of [`unset` on references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.unset.php) is by design. You could instead return the index of the element to remove, or an array of indices if the array isn't flat.

For example, you could use the following function:

```
function delItem(&$array, $indices) {
    $tmp =& $array;
    for ($i=0; $i < count($indices)-1; ++$i) {
        $key = $indices[$i];
        if (isset($tmp[$key])) {
            $tmp =& $tmp[$key];
        } else {
            return array_slice($indices, 0, $i+1);
        }
    }
    unset($tmp[$indices[$i]]);
    return False;
}
```

Or, if you prefer exceptions,

```
function delItem(&$array, $indices) {
    $tmp =& $array;
    while (count($indices) > 1) {
        $i = array_shift($indices);
        if (isset($tmp[$i])) {
            $tmp =& $tmp[$i];
        } else {
            throw new RangeException("Index '$i' doesn't exist in array.");
        }
    }
    unset($tmp[$indices[0]]);
}
```

Comment: if i get back an array of indexes (where the size of the array of indexes is n) how do i access the value to unset it?